# Solution of the differential equation $\sin(x\frac{dy}{dx})\cos(y)=\frac{dy}{dx}+\sin(y)\cos(x\frac{dy} {dx})$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Find the solution of the differential equation $\sin(x\frac{dy}{dx})\cos(y)=\frac{dy}{dx}+\sin(y)\cos(x\frac{dy}
{dx})$

My approach is as follow

$A=x\frac{dy}{dx}$

$\sin(A)\cos(y)-\cos(A)\sin(y)=\frac{dy}{dx}$

$\sin(A-y)=\frac{dy}{dx}$

$\sin(x\frac{dy}{dx}-y)=\frac{dy}{dx}$

After this step I am not able to solve it,

Comment: $ u=y/v,\,\sin(x^2 u')= xu'+u $ useful?

Answer (score 1):

From the last stage 
Take $p = \frac {dy}{dx}$

Then the equation becomes 
$\sin(px-y) =p$

Or, $y= px- \sin^{-1}p$,

It's an Clairaut's equation.

Differentiating with respect to $x$ on both sides,

We get    $$p= p+x\frac{dp}{dx}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-p^2}}\frac{dp}{dx}$$
Or,$$\frac{dp}{dx}(x-\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-p^2}})=0$$
Now,$\frac{dp}{dx}=0 $gives  $p=c$

Hence the general solution will be
 $$y= cx - \sin^{-1}c$$, where $c$ is constant.

Comment: There should be another solution corresponding to $x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-p^2}}$, no?

Comment: $x= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-p^2}} $ then $p^2=\frac{x^2-1}{x^2}$ ,now from $y=px- sin^{-1}p$,we have $$y=\sqrt{x^2-1}- sin^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x}$$, it's singular solution.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin(x\frac{dy}{dx}-y)=\frac{dy}{dx}$$
Differentiate;
$$\cos(xy'-y)y''x=y''$$
$$y''(\cos(xy'-y)x-1)=0$$
$$y''=0  \implies y=Cx+C_2 \tag 1$$
Plug to find the constants.
$$ C=-\sin(C_2)$$
$$ \implies y(x)=-x\sin(C_2)+C_2$$
 The second equation is :
$$ \cos(xy'-y)x =1 \tag 2$$
$$ \left ( \frac y x \right)'=\dfrac 1 {x^2}\arccos (1/x)$$
Integrate:
$$ y(x) =x\int \dfrac  {\arccos (1/x)dx}{x^2}$$